# Geolocation success callback - How do I work with the returned object outside this callback?

Tags: html, geolocation

Most of the simple html5 geolocation examples on the web go something like:

```
if(navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
} else {
    //no geolocation
}

function success(position) {
    //do things with the position object in here
}

function error (msg) {
    //log error codes etc here
}
```

I'd prefer not to have all my logic within the success callback (there's quite a bit). What's the best way of exposing the object passed to `success` to the parent scope? By using a closure within `success` somehow? I can't quite get it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason a callback function is required is because the call to getCurrentPosition is asynchronous. Therefore, while you can expose the position as a variable in scope of the "parent" (the scope in which getCurrentPosition is called), this isn't useful on the thread of execution that calls getCurrentPosition as this is different from that of the success function. For example, this won't work:

```
function parent(){
  var position;

  function success(p) {
    position = p;
  }

  function error (msg) {
    //log error codes etc here
  }

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
  var longitude = position.coords.longitude; // position is undefined here
}
```

However, if you want to break down your code into smaller chunks, you can store the position in a variable within scope of the parent (avoids needing to pass it through) and then chain multiple functions together:

```
function parent(){
  var position;

  function success(p) {
    position = p;
    doSomethingWithPosition();
  }

  function error (msg) {
    //log error codes etc here
  }

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);

  function doSomethingWithPosition(){
     var longitude = position.coords.longitude; // position is defined here
     doSomethingElseWithPosition();
  }

  function doSomethingElseWithPosition(){
     var latitude = position.coords.latitude; // position is defined here
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'd worked out something similar. The next question is: Do you think it's worth it?

Comment: Whether it's worth it entirely depends on what you do with it. I used the HTML5 geolocation API to develop GPS-enabled apps for Android & iOS via Phonegap. Equally, there's a whole lot of uses for it on mobile websites, etc.

Comment: Sorry I mean, is it worth breaking the code down in the way you've suggested, or just leave it within the `success` callback? Or is a different structure altogether better?

Comment: Oh, sorry, misunderstood. Depends how much code you have and how easy it is to tease apart the different elements of it. Whatever you find easier.