# Getting latitude/longitude from geolocation in javascript

Tags: javascript

I recently started to learn more javascript and was following this video for geolocations https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=916M64DuRnk&ab_channel=dcode . What I wanted was to get the latitudes and longitudes and store it in a variable so I can pass it into Google maps' geocode api to get the zip code. When I tried assigning it to a predefined variable outside of the scope, it said it can't be assigned an undefined.

```
        let lat;
        const sucessCall = (position) => {
            console.log(position.coords.latitude);
            lat= position.coords.latitude; //ERROR
        }
        const errorCall = (error) => {
            console.error(error);
        }
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(sucessCall, errorCall);
```

Please don't make things too complicated, I'm still fairly new to this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Geolocation success callback - How do I work with the returned object outside this callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19591012/geolocation-success-callback-how-do-i-work-with-the-returned-object-outside-th)

Comment: I use ```const { latitude } = position.coords;``` and it works perfectly. Which line shows the error and what is that?

Comment: I figured it out. I just stored the values within a scoped variable and then turned it into a cookie and then outside of the scope decoded it.